# How to tell if an address is a multisig?

Tags: etherscan, multisignature

I'm looking at an address owned by an investor on etherscan and am wondering if it's a multisig. Usually multisigs are contracts and you can tell if an address is a contract on etherscan, but are there types of multisigs that *aren't* contracts, that would show up the same as an external address on etherscan?

Comment: In Ethereum, the process of multi-signature can only be implemented programmatically (which is synonymous to using a contract).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All multisig addresses in Ethereum are contracts.